# Including default files and folders in User's home directory

Tags: user-management, users, user-accounts, user-permissions, user-profile

I'm using ubuntu server 14.04. I want to include some default files and folders in home directory for every user, whenever a new user account is created. How to make this. Can anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /etc/skel directory is what you're looking for. This directory is used as a template for new home directories.

Comment: Thanks buddy... Will you give me a little elaborate detail and steps..If possible with example.

Comment: @user72789 What research have you done on your own? This is a *very* simple process. You need to show us some effort that you've tried to *help yourself*.

Comment: I'm a fresh graduate (Electronics & communication). I want to drive my career path in linux administration. What I have done is jz simply copy the files and folders in /etc/skel that I want to be appear in every users home folder and add user accnts as usual #useradd <username>

Comment: @user72789 And did it work as expected?

Comment: No... The user accnt is created but the files that I kept in skel folder was not present in user's home directory. I'm using RHEL 6.4 on  VMware